# Is Flash a good skill to pick up?

Tags: flash

I've been a web programmer for two years now and feel like there are just certain things you can't do "well" unless you're using flash. I've never picked up flash because I didn't have the money to pay for it. I have recently found out there are many open source alternatives such as open laszlo and flashdevelop so I'm concediring picking it up.

1) Is flash a good skill to own as a web developer?
2) Do you think flash will be more and more apart of the web in the future?

Answer (score 7):

As much as this question is fundamentally unanswerable (All skills are good, If I knew what would be popular in the future, I'd be much richer than I am)...

1. SFlash is certainly popular on the web, clients may well want it, and having the string in your bow is not bad thing.
2. It's popularity will, I suspect, stay around about where it is. HTML 5 etc may put some pressure on it, as will Silverlight. I don't expect mass abandonment of it for either, but I can't see a huge upswing in usage either.

Comment: +1.  Although I would add another aspect that is chasing after the current position of Flash is JS frameworks such as JQuery in combination with new high speed javascript processing.

Comment: Silverlight hasn't taken off as much as Microsoft may have wanted. That said, it doesn't mean it won't of course.

Answer (score 4):

In my *opinion*... I believe that Flash is not required for much of what it is used for, and I think that people are beginning to realise the power and flexibility in pure Javascript. This is helped by libraries such as jQuery, making it a piece of cake to do things that usually would have seen people calling in the Flash designers immediately.

Regarding your question part #2... I think Flash will be less and less a part of the web in the future, purely because of the internet's natural tendency towards openness and standards.

I am personally not going to have fun if we have to watch Flash/Silverlight/etc. battle it all out before everyone comes to realise this again :)

Answer (score 0):

1)
I think that it depends on what your ambitions are. If you want to work mostly on the frontend and making things look pretty; Flash is certainly a skill that fits in your toolbox. If, on the other hand, you are more interested in making things work on the serverside, I would not invest my time very heavily in flash. As with most things, however, it does not hurt to know a little bit about everything, since it makes it easier when integrating things.

2) 
I think Flash will still be around for some time, because it is already widespread. Today, most computers will have Flash installed, so if you are developing a rich browser application, flash will be the safest bet. This may change with time, however, and there are serious competition to Flash available today - such as Silverlight or Flex. Personally, I find Silverlight more appealing (I'm a .NET guy), but wouldn't use it today for a widespread application, since many users won't have the runtime installed.

Comment: I wouldn't call Flex a competitor for flash, it's rather a compliment to Flash.

Answer (score 0):

There's a huge push in the Silverlight direction by Microsoft as well. I'd consider at least taking a look at it as it's not only taking off in the development community, but also in the enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in web development these days and I came to the same conclusion: at one point or another things would have been much easier had I known a bit of flash (like coding my own video player that actually acts as I expect it to and publishes a decent javascript interface).

However, I've tested Open Lazslo (and loved it) but I wouldn't consider it as a typical web development tool. It gets really useful when you have to somehow emulate a desktop application from within a browser (in term of UI). So I'd put it into the corporate intranet department.

As for the future of Flash and its relationship to the web, I have no idea. But if browser vendors get back to their senses and accept cross-domain ajax request that are explicitely authorized by a server (like flash does), the only use we will have of flash is for heavyweight applications like video players and animation-heavy games.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in learning something new you could give a look at [Haxe](https://haxe.org). It is one language with a lot of possibilities. It creates flashmovies (flash 6 - 11), generates server-side code (Neko/PHP) and JavaScript. It is open source, so it is also free.